# Cakephp Find Fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to retrieve one column per record by way of the find(). When I execute my code It returns all the fields in the table. Here is my code. What is wrong with my code? I am using Cakephp 1.3.

```
public function findPolicyIds($coverageId = null) {
    $id = $this->Policy->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1, array(
        'fields' => array('Policy.id'))));

        return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a extra array being formed. Try this:

```
public function findPolicyIds($coverageId = null) {   
$id = $this->Policy->find('all', array(
'recursive' => -1,
'fields' => array('Policy.id')));

return $id;
}
```

Code untested.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Now when I run my script, I see only the field I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `Model::field()`. I think that's what you want. [See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field)